Examples of global and local inertial frames
I am still struggling to grasp the difference between local and global inertial frames in special and general relativity and I would appreciate some concrete examples for

Global but not local inertial frame
Local but not global inertial frame
A frame that is neither locally or globally inertial
A frame that is both locally and globally inertial

Here are some examples I can think of:

A frame attached to an observer standing on an infinite plane with uniform gravitational field.
A frame attached to an observer undergoing free fall into a black hole.
A frame attached to an observer standing on Earth.
A frame attached to an astronaut stranded in space.

Is that right? Are there other examples I can add?

Newton stated his first law as "Every object perseveres in its state of rest, or of uniform motion in a right line, except insofar as it is compelled to change that state by forces impressed thereon." We can rephrase Newton's first law a little bit as 'An inertial reference frame is a frame where inertial objects continue in a state of rest or in a state of constant velocity in a straight line.' Here, an inertial object is an object that feels no proper acceleration, so an object in free fall can be an inertial object, even though it may appear to be accelerating from the point of view of a non-inertial observer. The surface of the Earth does not qualify as an inertial reference frame by this definition because if you release a ball from your hand, it obviously does not continue in its state of rest and accelerates towards the ground.
We can determine an observer is not in an inertial reference frame, if they experience proper acceleration. This is not really a separate condition to using Newton's first law to define an inertial reference frame, because the lack of proper force on an inertial observer is already implied by the first law.
Onboard an orbiting space station, an observer does not measure any proper force acting on themselves and they can consider themselves to be locally in an inertial reference frame. In Newtonian terms, the centrifugal force of the orbiting space station is said to balance the gravitational force that provides the inward centripetal force. The fact that an observer in orbit cannot measure any proper force acting on themselves, is because centrifugal force and the force of gravity are both fictitious forces and cannot be measured by an accelerometer attached to an inertial observer.

Global but not local inertial frame

It might be tempting to think that an observer in a rocket with proper acceleration in the hypothetical flat space of Minkowski spacetime might satisfy this condition. Certainly, the local reference frame of the observer is not inertial, but neither is the global flat space. Any test particles fired out into the flat space will not travel in straight lines from the observer's point of view, and so, the reference frame cannot be described as inertial on a global scale. As MakiseKurisu mentions in his answer, a global reference frame cannot exclude the local part, so no scenario can satisfy this pair of requirements.

Local but not global inertial frame

A free-falling observer falling towards a gravitational body can be described as being in an approximately inertial reference frame, locally. The local reference frame, in this case, is not an exact inertial reference frame, but the smaller the space and time under consideration, the closer the local volume approximates an inertial reference frame.
If an observer is falling towards an spherical gravitational body, they can arrange a spherical shell of particles around themselves to determine the local curvature of space. It is a curious fact that in curved spacetime this spherical shell will contract horizontally and elongate vertically over time while maintaining constant volume. If the sphere is small enough that the distortion is difficult to determine, then the volume of the shell can be considered as the volume within which the reference frame can be considered to be inertial for practical purposes.

A frame that is neither locally or globally inertial

Examples of locally non-inertial reference frames are the reference frames of an observer on an accelerating rocket, an observer on a carousel and an observer on the surface of the Earth. If a reference frame is not inertial at the local level then it is automatically not inertial at the global level. However, it should be noted that a reference frame that is not inertial can be approximately inertial over a small enough (possibly infinitesimal) interval of time and space. This is what is behind the concept of an instantaneous co-moving inertial reference frame that allows us to analyse an accelerating particle. It is also closely related to the "clock hypothesis", which allows us to determine the instantaneous time dilation of an accelerating clock by considering only its instantaneous velocity and completely ignoring its acceleration.

A frame that is both locally and globally inertial

A frame that is globally inertial is automatically locally inertial (but not vice versa). In reality, there is no globally inertial reference frame in our universe that contains gravitational matter and curved space. The only scenario that qualifies is an inertial observer in the hypothetical flat space of Minkowski spacetime, which assumes an empty universe with no gravitational matter anywhere.
A frame attached to an observer free falling towards an infinite plane with a uniform gravitational field, would be very close to a frame that is both locally and globally inertial. The lack of tidal forces would make the reference frame appear inertial over considerable distances, but it debatable if this scenario can be considered to be a global inertial reference frame in the most general sense. Certainly the reference frame has a limited time span because it will inevitably hit the gravitational surface.
Although it does not fit neatly into one of the above categories, the case of the set of Rindler observers is an interesting example. If they are all moving in the same direction, they all appear to be stationary with respect to each other. However, if they release test particles at different heights, they will see the inertial test particles move away from each other over time indicating they are not in an inertial reference frame. They could of course arrive at the same conclusion, by simply measuring their own proper accelerations using personal accelerometers and noting that they do not have zero proper acceleration.

Nice answer (+1) Suppose one is in the middle of the sea. The local inertial frame would be a boat that is floating un-steered, right? The global inertial frame would then be something that requires infinite knowledge of the entire sea, entire earth, entire solar system, entire galaxy, entire universe... Since this knowledge is practically impossible to attain, might it be cleaner to say that global inertial frame does not exist or is unknowable? Nothing local will depend on the global inertial frame anyway, so there seems no utility even if such a frame is defined?

@James The second part of your comment seems reasonable. The use of a boat on the sea does not work so well, because of the proper acceleration acting on an observer in the boat due to gravity. An unpowered space station in free fall in space would be a better approximation of a local inertial reference frame, I think.

thank you. Suppose there is a big whirlpool in the sea, and the boat is rotating around it (sorry I could not think up a plausible space scenario involving a spaceship), then even as the boat is constantly rotating around the whirlpool, the boat is in fact in its local inertial frame the whole time, so it won't radiate bremsstrahlung even as it rotates, do you think?

@James Unfortunately that suggests an electron would never radiate, which is not always true. One way to determine if you reference frame is not inertial is to check your proper acceleration. If you have a test mass attached to a spring, the spring will be stretched if you are non-inertial. The observer in the boat will see the spring stretched by centripetal force, so they will know they not inertial.  Onboard an orbiting space station, an observer does not measure any proper force acting on themselves and they can consider themselves to be locally in an inertial reference frame..

@James added a bit to my answer to cover proper acceleration.

thank you. Just one last quick clarification, suppose the boat is windowless except for a glass bottom that allows the people inside to see a few inches of water directly underneath the boat, could people inside the boat determine whether or not they are under proper acceleration by looking at the water body immediately underneath the boat? e.g. still water under the boat means no proper acceleration, while moving water under the boat means proper acceleration?

@james Unfortunately that does not work. Suppose the water-boat interface is frictionless. If we push the boat from the shore, the boat can move away inertially with constant velocity, but the water particles are moving relative to the observer on the boat. Assuming relative motion of the water means non-inertial motion gives the incorrect result. In the case of the boat in a whirlpool, the water is also moving in circles and the observer on the boat sees the water as stationary, but if he assumed that meant he had inertial motion he would be wrong.

@James Remember I mentioned that inertial objects remain at rest or continue in a straight line in an inertial reference frame? In the case of the water particles in the whirlpool that appear to be stationary, you have to remember the water particles are not inertial objects, but are being accelerated by gravity and whatever is causing the circular motion of the water in the whirlpool.

thank you. Sorry for the merry-go-round, I am still not sure what is it I wanted to ask, but I think this is all about bremsstrahlung radiation. Suppose there is a sensitive electron that will "shout" a photon out whenever it is pressed. Now we put this electron near the whirlpool as above. Since all the water particles surrounding this electron are stationary w.r.t. to this electron, then nothing will be "pressing" this electron even though both the electron and the water particles are not in an inertial frame, so then this electron in the whirlpool would not radiate a bremsstrahlung?

Imagine two rockets connected by a spring and arranged like a Catherine wheel so that when the rockets accelerate the assembly rotates. The connecting spring will stretch and the stretched spring provides the inwards centripetal force. This centripetal force is equal to the proper force an observer riding on one of the rockets experiences and this tells the observer he is not in an inertial reference frame. To an observer on the wheel, the rockets appear stationary but even he agrees the springs are stretched and everyone agrees the rotating frame is not inertial.   T.B.C..

Now imagine we get a bunch of rockets to fly around in circles following the two spring tethered rockets. This will not change the length of the stretched spring or the proper force experienced by the circulating rockets. We can imagine one of  the rockets represents the electron. The circulating electron will experience proper acceleration and will radiate as a result and the presence of comoving water molecules will not change anything. It is the proper acceleration that provides what you call "pressing" and causes the radiation.

If you are looking for the reason why electrons do not spiral into the nucleus you will not solve the conundrum by proposing that electron is moving inertially. The real answer involves a deep dive into quantum mechanics and in the modern interpretation the electron does not literally orbit the nucleus like a physical satellite.

Thank you for the detailed answer! It cleared almost all my lingering doubts. It seems like in Newtonian mechanics and special relativity, gravity is perceived as a force, so global inertial frames exist because Newton's first law is satisfied. All objects in a global inertial frame exhibit inertia. They remain in rest or move in straight line unless there's a force (in particular gravity) acting on it.

In general relativity, it is no longer the case since gravity is now seen as another kind of fictitious force. In an inertial frame that is global in Newtonian mechanics and special relativity, Newton's first law is violated: there are some objects accelerating due to gravity (which is a fictitious force). So global inertial frames cannot exist.

I think your definition is not clear. Because "global" intuitively means "for every place", how can a  global frame exclude the local part?
And the term "local" means for some certain region (always infinitesimal) so how can it be global?
If we use the usual definition of these concepts,then
Only for flat spacetime, we have global inertial reference frame. where global means everywhere and inertial means no gravity,so only flat spacetime has no gravity everywhere.
For curved spacetime, we can always construct locally inertial reference frame.Physically corresponding to the equivalence principle and mathematically corresponding to the Fermi coordiante (also called Riemann normal coordinate).
EDIT:
I see. But I guess your definition is not quite good. Suppose A is a free falling observer, by the equivalence principle, A don't know whether A is free falling in a gravitational field or just a observer without acceleration in flat spacetime.
But, the previous discussion only works for a small lab. Mathematically, the lab should exactly be 1 point or 1 line on the spacetime manifold which has no volume, this means for very real lab (which must have a finite volume), we can always, if ignore the experimental condition, clarify whether this lab is in a gravitational field or in flat spacetime. If we find the physical law in our lab exactly satisfy the special relativity, then our spacetime must be flat and we can define the global inertial frame. But if we find there exists a difference caused by gravity, then we can claim there is no global inertial frame.
Back to your comment, we can just perform the experiment: send a light beam in this lab and check its behavior, if the behavior perfectly fits special relativity, then you can claim that every frame attached with an inertial observer is a global inertial frame, although you can just design a lab with finite volume, but in principle it can be as large as possible.
If the light not fits SR, then we can claim there is no global inertial frame, also no physically local inertial frame because it always has a finite volume. The only thing we can do is to design the volume of lab as small as possible and all experiment in this lab will not be strongly affected by gravity. And if the lab is attached to a free falling observer, then the result of the experiment will almost behave like in a inertial frame.

Thank you. I am sure about the exact definition of local and global inertial frames. I imagine a reference frame attached to an observer can be likened to a windowless box-shaped laboratory. A local frame corresponds to a laboratory whose width, length and height are finite while a global frame corresponds to a laboratory whose width, length and height are infinite. A frame is inertial iff an observer inside the lab observes that laws of physics are satisfied in every inch of the lab.

@user366875 I see,I edited by answer hoping it would be helpful
